# Are scalar and vector potentials solutions to Maxwell's equations?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

Are scalar and vector potentials $\phi = 0$, $\vec{A} = A_0 \cos (kx-\omega t) \hat{e}_z$ solutions to Maxwell's equations?
Do these potentials correspond to the Lorentz and Coulomb calibration?

Comment: Have you tried plugging them in to see what happens? (By the way, by $kx$ do you mean $k\cdot x$?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> Are scalar and vector potentials $\phi = 0$, $\vec{A} = A_0 \cos (kx-\omega t) \hat{e}_z$ solutions to Maxwell's equations?

They could be. It depends on what the source terms ($\rho$ and $\vec J$) are equal to. It also depends on the relationship between $k$ and $\omega$. Since you have not stated any of this context in your question, I will not say whether or not they are solutions, only that they could be solutions under some circumstances.

> Do these potentials correspond to the Lorentz and Coulomb calibration?

Not sure what the term "calibration" means in this context. Do you mean "gauge"? Again, you should provide us that context not vice versa. As mentioned above, in some circumstances these fields can be solutions.